# Android Preferences to Layout

Tags: android, android-studio, sharedpreferences, android-preferences

How to use this code `Preferences.xml`

```
<PreferenceCategory android:title="Remote Proxy" android:key="plugin">
        <CheckBoxPreference android:title="Use Remote Proxy" android:key="remote" android:defaultValue="false" />
        <ListPreference android:entries="@array/entries_list_preference" android:layout="?android:preferenceLayoutChild" android:title="Proxy Type" android:key="0Handler: 9" android:summary="Choose proxy type" android:dependency="remote" android:dialogTitle="Choose Proxy Type" android:entryValues="@array/entryvalues_list_preference" />
        <ListPreference android:entries="@array/headerlist" android:layout="?android:preferenceLayoutChild" android:title="Custom Header" android:key="0Handler: 10" android:summary="Choose custom header" android:dependency="remote" android:dialogTitle="Choose custom header" android:entryValues="@array/headervalue" />
        <ListPreference android:entries="@array/serverlist" android:layout="?android:preferenceLayoutChild" android:title="Proxy Server" android:key="0Handler: 11" android:summary="Choose proxy server" android:dependency="remote" android:dialogTitle="Choose Proxy Server" android:entryValues="@array/servervalue" />
        <ListPreference android:entries="@array/proxytypelist" android:layout="?android:preferenceLayoutChild" android:title="Real Proxy Type" android:key="0Handler: 14" android:summary="Choose proxy type" android:dependency="remote" android:dialogTitle="Choose Proxy Type" android:entryValues="@array/servertype" />
    </PreferenceCategory>
```

In `Layout.xml`, How can I activate my `SharedPreferences` without using `Android ID`?

Answer (score 0):

You can't use Preferences in a layout.

Correct usage is in `res/xml`.

See http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/settings.html#DefiningPrefs